# Razor (.cshtml) editor code block format settings

Tags: visual-studio, razor-pages

I am running Visual Studio 16.8.1, when editing a Razor `.cshtml` file and applying a reformat (CTRL+K+D) the editor moves braces and elements in a code block starting with `@`

For example if I have the code:

```
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
    ViewData["Title"] = "My Page";
}

@if (Model.ShowRequestId)
{
    <p>
        <strong>Request ID:</strong> <code>@Model.RequestId</code>
    </p>
}
```

And I reformat the file by pressing CTRL+K+D it will move the fist line to the same line as the `@{` and move the closing brace right after the last element like:

```
@{ Layout = "_Layout";
                ViewData["Title"] = "My Page"; }

@if (Model.ShowRequestId)
{
<p>
    <strong>Request ID:</strong> <code>@Model.RequestId</code>
</p>}
```

Is there a way to control when VS inserts or removes new lines and indenting before and after the braces so it formats like the first example? I have searched through the `Options->Text Editor->{editor}->Formatting` groups and can't find anything that seems to control this behavior, is this a bug in the VS editor or am I just missing the setting somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it was fixed in Visual Studio Version 16.8.2